# Как правильно очистить файлы journal?

Tags: linux

посмотрел сколько места занимают журналы.

```
cf@cf:/var/log$ sudo du -BM -d 1 .
1M  ./suricata
1M  ./samba
1M  ./dist-upgrade
1M  ./cups
2033M   ./journal
1M  ./private
1M  ./apache2
1M  ./hp
1M  ./apt
1M  ./clamav
1M  ./gdm3
2M  ./teamviewer15
1M  ./openvpn
1M  ./mysql
1M  ./unattended-upgrades
2M  ./installer
1M  ./speech-dispatcher
2147M   .
```

в каталоге journal много файлов, и что из них можно удалить и как это удобней следать не понятно.

```
cf@cf:/var/log$ ls journal/6af7eb7200e94c6b8f6f0fe85f33272e/
system@0005ae43cc81ffe2-256fcc1b9d9b7e79.journal~                                  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-00000000000005d9-0005ad47d1c94a11.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-0000000000000001-0005ae43cc815bd9.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000000c78-0005ad43a28efa86.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-00000000001fd5fa-0005ae7de6cc4f37.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-000000000000883d-0005ad4565c2f517.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-0000000000205e84-0005ae82b6123390.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000014cbc-0005ad46186220e5.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-000000000023070b-0005ae94d310f040.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000036e02-0005ad66a11a8ede.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-0000000000248de0-0005aea7435b1ed7.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000051394-0005ad6ea5fd22d5.journal
system@074693ea4a1f4a128734c52b6b759b0e-0000000000273994-0005aebdee831999.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-000000000007cf17-0005ad7c8e4bc017.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000000001-0005ad47d186e6cf.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000097a3c-0005ad7f2e0b1e80.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000000c77-0005ad43a2836432.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-000000000009bfd6-0005ad82e05f6041.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-000000000000883c-0005ad4565bf0bb6.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-00000000000d5a5d-0005adb41f53bd5c.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000014cb7-0005ad46184eba56.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-00000000000fc4cf-0005adb487e87d0d.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000036e01-0005ad66a105a573.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-000000000012f26b-0005addb197c33fd.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000051393-0005ad6ea5de322f.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000158466-0005adef8347df25.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-000000000007b7c3-0005ad7c89fa7fd0.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000189de1-0005ae09c955e384.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000097a3b-0005ad7f2dfc9895.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-00000000001b5d11-0005ae15c9052cf4.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-000000000009bfcd-0005ad82e041459e.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-00000000001fd60f-0005ae7de6e66235.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-00000000000d080e-0005adb41155a8be.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000205e85-0005ae82b6301189.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-00000000000fb38f-0005adb4854d5053.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000231c5f-0005ae94d96468b0.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-000000000012a292-0005addb0f01a4fd.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-0000000000248de1-0005aea743873297.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000158388-0005adef82dd5bca.journal  user-1000@d983f84bbf234cbb92f8cf0075df3861-000000000027407c-0005aebdef6162b1.journal
system@cdd0bb724e584ae0948f9403395fc5f1-0000000000189d17-0005ae09c93056a5.journal  user-1000.journal
system.journal
cf@cf:/var/log$
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Journal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если удалить папку /var/log/journal, то журнал будет писаться только во временную папку.

А настроить рамер журнала можно в /etc/systemd/journald.conf

```
SystemMaxUse=50M
```